# How do I inform other applications that my application is a part of the Windows desktop?

Tags: c#, windows, toolbar

I would like to create a "toolbar" for windows in c# and would like to fit it the in top space of the Windows desktop.

I would like the other windows program not be able to overlay my application. I also want other applications to treat my window as a part of the desktop so that when they maximize, you can still see my application.

Comment: If you mean that you want to limit the size of the Windows desktop when your program is running, try this: ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx )

Comment: @Michael Todd: If it's the answer, post it! You can also add an excerpt to give the answer more substance.

Answer (score 9):

You can create what is called an Application Desktop Toolbar. Your application will essentially communicate with the Windows Shell (and, consequently, other applications) to instruct the desktop how it should interact with your application.

This type of functionality is not built into .Net, but there's an excellent tutorial available to do this on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx).

Comment: I didn't even know this was possible!

Comment: Great link!  Please don't refrain from "answering" with a simple link.  You deserve recognition for 1) reading the linked page some time ago  2) remembering that you read the page  3) remembering how to find the page again and  4) taking the time to share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

Use the toolstrip control in the Windows Form designer.