# Create toolbar for windows 8 like Bing Desktop

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, taskbar

I would like to create toolbar with a text box in the windows8 taskbar using C# similar to what Bing Desktop has.

[image]

I found this code example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and

but it doesn't work.. it does add an add-on to IE but not to the windows taskbar.

Does anyone know of a good example that I can learn from?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365681/how-do-i-inform-other-applications-that-my-application-is-a-part-of-the-windows?rq=1

Comment: thank you. it's not exactly what I meant, the Bing box is inside the windows taskbar beside the trey and clock area.

Comment: [Microsoft recommends against writing managed in-process extensions to Windows Explorer or Windows Internet Explorer and does not consider them a supported scenario.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089(v=vs.85).aspx)